# What is TMonitor in Delphi System unit good for?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-2009, delphi-xe, tmonitor

After reading the articles ["Simmering Unicode, bring DPL to a boil"](https://blog.therealoracleatdelphi.com/2008/01/simmering-unicode-bring-dpl-to-boil_17.html) and ["Simmering Unicode, bring DPL to a boil (Part 2)"](https://blog.therealoracleatdelphi.com/2008/01/simmering-unicode-bring-dpl-to-boil_83.html) of "The Oracle at Delphi" (Allen Bauer), Oracle is all I understand :)

The article mentions Delphi Parallel Library (DPL), lock free data structures, [mutual exclusion locks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) and [condition variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_variable) (this Wikipedia article forwards to '[Monitor (synchronization)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29)', and then introduces the new [TMonitor record type](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.TMonitor) for thread synchronization and describes some of its methods.

Are there introduction articles with examples which show when and how this Delphi record type can be used? There is some [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.TMonitor) online.

- What is the main difference between TCriticalSection and TMonitor?
- What can I do with the `Pulse` and `PulseAll`methods?
- Does it have a counterpart for example in C# or the Java language?
- Is there any code in the RTL or the VCL which uses this type (so it could serve as an example)?

---

Update: the article [Why Has the Size of TObject Doubled In Delphi 2009?](https://web.archive.org/web/20090328064412/http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/03/25/38138/) explains that every object in Delphi now can be locked using a TMonitor record, at the price of four extra bytes per instance.

It looks like TMonitor is implemented similar to [Intrinsic Locks in the Java language](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html):

> Every object has an intrinsic lock
> associated with it. By convention, a
> thread that needs exclusive and
> consistent access to an object's
> fields has to acquire the object's
> intrinsic lock before accessing them,
> and then release the intrinsic lock
> when it's done with them.

[Wait](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.TMonitor.Wait), [Pulse](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.TMonitor.Pulse) and [PulseAll](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.TMonitor.PulseAll) in Delphi seem to be counterparts of [wait()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29), [notify()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29) and [notifyAll()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll%28%29) in the Java programming language. Correct me if I am wrong :)

---

Update 2: **Example code for a Producer/Consumer application** using `TMonitor.Wait` and `TMonitor.PulseAll`, based on an article about guarded methods in the [Java(tm) tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) (comments are welcome):

> This kind of application shares data
> between two threads: the producer,
> that creates the data, and the
> consumer, that does something with it.
> The two threads communicate using a
> shared object. Coordination is
> essential: the consumer thread must
> not attempt to retrieve the data
> before the producer thread has
> delivered it, and the producer thread
> must not attempt to deliver new data
> if the consumer hasn't retrieved the
> old data.

In this example, the data is a series of text messages, which are shared through an object of type Drop:

```
program TMonitorTest;

// based on example code at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Classes;

type
  Drop = class(TObject)
  private
    // Message sent from producer to consumer.
    Msg: string;
    // True if consumer should wait for producer to send message, false
    // if producer should wait for consumer to retrieve message.
    Empty: Boolean;
  public
    constructor Create;
    function Take: string;
    procedure Put(AMessage: string);
  end;

  Producer = class(TThread)
  private
    FDrop: Drop;
  public
    constructor Create(ADrop: Drop);
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

  Consumer = class(TThread)
  private
    FDrop: Drop;
  public
    constructor Create(ADrop: Drop);
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

{ Drop }

constructor Drop.Create;
begin
  Empty := True;
end;

function Drop.Take: string;
begin
  TMonitor.Enter(Self);
  try
    // Wait until message is available.
    while Empty do
    begin
      TMonitor.Wait(Self, INFINITE);
    end;
    // Toggle status.
    Empty := True;
    // Notify producer that status has changed.
    TMonitor.PulseAll(Self);
    Result := Msg;
  finally
    TMonitor.Exit(Self);
  end;
end;

procedure Drop.Put(AMessage: string);
begin
  TMonitor.Enter(Self);
  try
    // Wait until message has been retrieved.
    while not Empty do
    begin
      TMonitor.Wait(Self, INFINITE);
    end;
    // Toggle status.
    Empty := False;
    // Store message.
    Msg := AMessage;
    // Notify consumer that status has changed.
    TMonitor.PulseAll(Self);
  finally
    TMonitor.Exit(Self);
  end;
end;

{ Producer }

constructor Producer.Create(ADrop: Drop);
begin
  FDrop := ADrop;
  inherited Create(False);
end;

procedure Producer.Execute;
var
  Msgs: array of string;
  I: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Msgs, 4);
  Msgs[0] := 'Mares eat oats';
  Msgs[1] := 'Does eat oats';
  Msgs[2] := 'Little lambs eat ivy';
  Msgs[3] := 'A kid will eat ivy too';
  for I := 0 to Length(Msgs) - 1 do
  begin
    FDrop.Put(Msgs[I]);
    Sleep(Random(5000));
  end;
  FDrop.Put('DONE');
end;

{ Consumer }

constructor Consumer.Create(ADrop: Drop);
begin
  FDrop := ADrop;
  inherited Create(False);
end;

procedure Consumer.Execute;
var
  Msg: string;
begin
  repeat
    Msg := FDrop.Take;
    WriteLn('Received: ' + Msg);
    Sleep(Random(5000));
  until Msg = 'DONE';
end;

var
  ADrop: Drop;
begin
  Randomize;
  ADrop := Drop.Create;
  Producer.Create(ADrop);
  Consumer.Create(ADrop);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Now this works as expected, however there is a detail which I could improve: instead of locking the whole Drop instance with `TMonitor.Enter(Self);`, I could choose a fine-grained locking approach, with a (private) "FLock" field, using it only in the Put and Take methods by `TMonitor.Enter(FLock);`.

If I compare the code with the Java version, I also notice that there is no `InterruptedException` in Delphi which can be used to cancel a call of `Sleep`.

**Update 3**: in May 2011, a [blog entry](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2011/05/tmonitor-bug.html) about the OmniThreadLibrary presented a possible bug in the TMonitor implementation. It seems to be related to an entry in [Quality Central](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=78415). The comments mention a patch has been provided by a Delphi user, but it is not visible.

**Update 4**: A [blog post](http://delphitools.info/2013/06/06/tmonitor-vs-trtlcriticalsection/) in 2013 showed that while TMonitor is 'fair', its performance is worse than that of a critical section.

Comment: `TMonitor` had severe bugs, which were finally corrected in XE2 upd 4. The errors could be manifested by the TMonitor use in `TThreadedQueue`. See [`TThreadedQueue not capable of multiple consumers?`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4856306/576719) for more information.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TMonitor combines the notion of a critical section (or a simple mutex) along with a condition variable. You can read about what a "monitor" is here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29

Any place you would use a critical section, you can use a monitor. Instead of declaring a `TCriticalSection`, you can simple create a `TObject` instance and then use that:

```
TMonitor.Enter(FLock);
try
  // protected code
finally
  TMonitor.Exit(FLock);
end;
```

Where `FLock` is any object instance. Normally, I just create a `TObject`:

```
FLock := TObject.Create;
```

Comment: So this `FLock` is the monitor in this example? (the "object intended to be used safely by more than one thread" as described in Wikipedia)

Comment: FLock is any object instance. It can be just a simple TObject instance. FLock := TObject.Create;

Comment: Still not enough. You have shown how to emulate a critical section with TMonitor, but sure that is not the real problem the TMonitor was designed for. Can you give a more interesting code example?

Comment: You might also want to add some information why you chose to add to the VCL the generally reviled ability to lock any object. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad.

Comment: Mjustin, I wouldn't say `FLock` *is* the monitor in this example. It *has* a monitor, and we're using it to protect some code. If we already had some other TObject, we'd probably have used its monitor instead of creating a new object for that sole purpose. It isn't necessarily the object being *used* by multiple threads — that's whatever is used inside the try-finally section — but to have any benefit at all, the other threads will need to know about `FLock` so they can wait on the same object. (Just like a critical section, it's useless if only one thread uses it.)

Comment: @Rob: Wikipedia defines Monitor as 'an object intended to be used safely by more than one thread' - in the example one locked object (FLock) is used to protect code in a different object. The article mghie links says that it is bad idea to create a global lock on the object ("Why is lock(this) {…} bad?"). Other threads do not need to 'know' (have access to) FLock, FLock can be a private instance variable, only used in one synchronized method.

Comment: Other threads *do* need to know about `FLock`, or at least the object `FLock` refers to. That's not the same as saying other portions of *code* need to know about it. It could indeed be a private instance variable, but then other threads need to call methods on that instance. The object cannot be stored solely in a local variable; it needs to be accessible to multiple threads. I don't mean TThread objects, just ordinary OS threads of execution.

Comment: I have added example code for a Producer/Consumer application, using TMonitor.Wait and TMonitor.PulseAll. It locks on the shared container object, but I added a note that it could also implement fine-grained locking.